# self.addSubView not working on iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, iad

I have an app that attempts to retrieve an iAd and if is unsuccessful loads an AdMob ad. It works perfectly on iPhone but when run on iPad I get a continuous loop that prevents the app from loading. Here's some code:

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{

 @try {
     NSLog(@"Ad Error, looking for AdMob Ad...");

    // Create a view of the standard size at the bottom of the screen.
    bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]
                   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                            self.view.frame.size.height -
                                            GAD_SIZE_320x50.height,
                                             GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                                            GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];

    // I know the banner size is incorret for iPad but it's only supposed to run
    // on iPad in compatibility mode and changing doesn't help

    // Specify the ad's "unit identifier." This is your AdMob Publisher ID.
    bannerView_.adUnitID = @"XXXXXXX";


    // Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
    // the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
    bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

   GADRequest *admobRequest =  [GADRequest request];

   admobRequest.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               GAD_SIMULATOR_ID,                               
                               nil];

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
    [bannerView_ loadRequest: admobRequest]; 


    [iAdBanner setHidden: YES]; 
    [bannerView_ setHidden: NO];
}
@catch (NSException *e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
}
@finally {
}
}
```

The `NSLog` prints out continuously and the app doesn't load.

```
012-02-24 21:58:38.991 TrophyConverter Free[2948:15e03] Ad Error, looking for AdMob Ad...
2012-02-24 21:58:38.992 TrophyConverter Free[2948:15e03] Ad Error, looking for AdMob Ad...
2012-02-24 21:58:38.994 TrophyConverter Free[2948:15e03] Ad Error, looking for AdMob Ad...
```

Has anyone else experienced this? How do I over come it? I've managed to use a `bool` to stop the continuous log printing and load the app but no Ad is shown.

**EDIT:**
The issue completely disappears when I remove this line

```
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
```

which isn't helpful since this is the part that adds the AdMob view.

I've also tried changing the build target to be a universal app rather than a iPhone app. This fixes the problem but I don't want it to be a universal app and I have no layouts created for it.

Comment: @MyztikJenz there is no error, didFailToReceiveAdWithError keeps being called once [self.view addSubView: bannerView_] is reached. It's like a never ending loop. Eventually I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS and during debug I can't view self.view so I guess it's something to do with that. I'm using ARC though so there are not early releases or anything

Comment: @MyztikJenz I have a crash log from Apple if that would help you. I noticed you work for them :)

Comment: So you're saying the `error` parameter is nil when this method gets recursively called? Adding the crash log to the problem would be helpful as well.

Comment: @MyztikJenz Sorry no I misunderstood, the NSError is "Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable" UserInfo=0x8181e20 {ADInternalErrorCode=3, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad inventory unavailable}". How shall I post the crash log - just paste it in the question, it's quite long...?

Comment: I don't think you're crash log will be helpful... You're most likely crashing due to the infinite recursion blowing the stack. I have no experience with GADBannerView but I bet it's seeing you're on an iPad but are specifying an iPhone sized ad. You either need to fix the size of the ad, figure out how why there is no ad inventory available, or just exit out without showing an ad when you get this error.

Comment: @MyztikJenz Yeah U guessed the same but I tried changing the size and it didn't help. I think I'm going to go for the latter because I really can't figure this out. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: The error you're getting is from iAd, not Google Ads. Have you tried removing the ADBannerView from the hierarchy when it fails? Seems like iAds is having issues and not Google Ads.

Comment: @MyztikJenz Removing the banner from the hierarchy didn't work :/ The issue comes when I'm adding the Admob banner and if I skip that the didFailToReceiveAdWithError method is never called again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a fix for this in the end so I basically added a bool that was switched once one fail had been made. Then no ad would be added if the check had been done and not already worked.